# Invoke-WebRequest Error in POST request in Flask API

Tags: api, flask

On POST request I'm getting this error -

````
D:\MyFiles\REST_API> curl -i -H "Content-Type: Application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/courses
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -i -H "Content-Type: Application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1: ...
+      ~~
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand```
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply mentioning 'curl' I have used "curl.exe" and issue got resolved.